# Read-only properties of timer callback functions

Tags: matlab, timer, callback

I would like to use the read option of `TasksExecuted` in a timer callback function. How could I proceed? Here is my program draft:

```
period=5
a = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',period,'TimerFcn',{@time_append,period,TasksExecuted, HR, fictiveFolderName},'TasksToExecute',3 );
start(a);

function time_append(obj,event,period,TasksExecuted, HR, fictiveFolderName)
        HR_freq=1;
        print(TasksExecuted);
        i_init=TasksExecuted*period*HR_freq+1
        i_end=(TasksExecuted+1)*period*HR_freq
        writematrix(HR(i_init:i_end),strcat(fictiveFolderName,'\HR.csv'),'WriteMode','append');
end
```

where `HR` is a 100x1 doubles matrix and `fictiveFolderName` an existing folder containing a csv file called HR. I get the error `Unrecognized function or variable 'TasksExecuted'`. There is only little information about read-only properties of callback functions available [in the documentation](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timer.html).

How can I use the read property of `TasksExecuted`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are after is a property of the timer object. Within your callback function you would have access to it as `obj.TasksExecuted`.

You won’t have access to it when creating the timer object (the line `a=timer…` where you get an error), because then the timer object doesn’t exist yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I changed that way 
`a = timer('ExecutionMode','fixedRate','Period',period,'TimerFcn',{@time_append,period,HR, fictiveFolderName},'TasksToExecute',3 );
start(a);

function time_append(obj,event,period,HR, fictiveFolderName)
        HR_freq=1;
        print(obj.TasksExecuted);
        i_init=obj.TasksExecuted*period*HR_freq+1
        i_end=(obj.TasksExecuted+1)*period*HR_freq
        writematrix(HR(i_init:i_end),strcat(fictiveFolderName,'\HR.csv'),'WriteMode','append');
end`. but I get a error `Handle input argument contains nonhandle values.` Do you know why?

Comment: ok I found the mistake from my previous comment, it was really stupid. I used `print` rather than `disp`